# Typescript emitted no output for '/path/to/file.ts'

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I have a library written with typescript. I can transpile it using `tsc` and with the configuration below without any problems.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "es5",
      "dom",
      "es2017"
    ],
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "listEmittedFiles": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "./dist",
    "./test",
    "./bin"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./lib"
  ]
}
```

But when another project tries to use this library from a linked npm package, it fails to transpile and bundle using `webpack` and `ts-loader`. For all the files of the library webpack gets error:

> Error: Typescript emitted no output for /library/path/to/file.ts

Note: *webpack tries to load it from the linked destination not from `node_modules` as it is linked with npm*.

---

Webpack configuration of the project uses library is below.

```
module.exports = (entry, dist) => Object.assign({
  entry,
  mode: "production",
  output: {
    filename: "index.js",
    path: dist,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".ts"]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  stats: 'verbose'
});
```

tsconfig.json of the project uses library

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "es5",
      "dom",
      "es2017"
    ],
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "./dist"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./index.ts"
  ]
}
```

And an example of library file that is not emitting output:

```
import {Ctor, Injector} from "./injector";
import {ERROR_CODES, PuzzleError} from "./errors";
import {Route} from "./server";


export interface ApiEvents {}

export interface ApiConfig {
  route: Route;
  subApis?: Array<Ctor<Api>>;
}

interface ApiBase {
}

export function PuzzleApi<T>(config: ApiConfig) {
  return Injector.decorate((constructor: () => void) => {
    console.log(`Registering Api: ${constructor.name}`);

  }, config);
}

export class Api implements ApiBase {
  config: ApiConfig;

  constructor() {
    const config = (this.constructor as any).config as ApiConfig;

    if (!config) {
      throw new PuzzleError(ERROR_CODES.CLASS_IS_NOT_DECORATED, this.constructor.name);
    } else {
      this.config = config;
    }
  }
}
```

I couldn't find any reason why it is not emitting output for that project. I can transpile the library without any problems. Can someone help me about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this error if the application tries to import a TypeScript source file from the library (i.e., from the `lib` subdirectory).  Try importing the generated JavaScript file from the `dist` subdirectory instead.  If you really want to recompile the library as part of the application, you probably need to add it to your `"include"` list in the `tsconfig.json` of the application.

Comment: "If you really want to recompile the library as part of the application..."

This did not work in my case.